# Same object, different parameters

Tags: jquery

I have this variable in jQuery

```
var link = $("<a />").css({
    "display" : "block"
});
```

Its source for another variables like this two:

```
var gmaps = link.clone().css({
  "background" : "red"
});
var google = link.clone().css({
  "background" : "blue"
});
```

For exemple this two should have their have different href parameter. How can I make it?

Comment: Not sure where you're stuck. Just have `gmaps.attr("href", "url here");` in order to assign href parameter to the link, and same for `google` just with different URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update href before the clone process:

```
var link = $("<a />").css({
    "display" : "block"
});

link.attr('href', 'http://link1.com/');
var gmaps = link.clone().css({
  "background" : "red"
});
link.attr('href', 'http://link2.com/');
var google = link.clone().css({
  "background" : "blue"
});
```